# Android Change Toolbar Background Color in Dark Mode

Tags: android, kotlin

Where I can change Toolbar background color in dark mode? I don't have custom Toolbar. I Would Like to change it in Themes. I've changed in **light mode : colorPrimaryVariant** and this changed me background of Toolbar, but when I do the same in my night xml file, then app doesn't react. Why?

My xml code looks like this:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.FastDraw" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/iconLightGrey</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/iconDarkGrey</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ToolBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Did you change it in your device settings to check it out?
You will need to go Settings -> Display -> Theme and enable dark mode then you will see the colors you choose in the dark theme

Comment: Yes I did. For example color primary change this bar above Toolbar but I cant change Toolbar background

Answer (score 0):

I believe since you are using a custom style already for your toolbar, you ought to change in that and assign there.

```xml
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/....</item>
    </style>
```